# How to run only once a pine script function?

Tags: function, pine-script, trading

here is a short code, his purpose in tradingview (thanks to pine script editor) is to draw a minimum line when the first argument is -1 and a maximum one when it is 1
[image: in theory i want the red line]
[image]
[image]
[image: what i have actually]

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Cryptocharl

//@version=4
study("Mon Script",overlay=true)
tunnel(n,f,long) =>
    if n==-1
        indref=0
        ind=indref+1
        pente=f[indref]-f[indref+1]
        for i=2 to long
            if  (f[indref]-f[indref+i])/i>pente
                pente := (f[indref]-f[indref+i])/i
                ind :=indref+i
        line.new(x1=bar_index[indref],y1=f[indref],x2=bar_index[ind],y2=f[ind],color=#FF5733 )
    else
        indref=0
        ind=indref+1
        pente=f[indref]-f[indref+1]
        for i=2 to long
            if  (f[indref]-f[indref+i])/i<pente
                pente := (f[indref]-f[indref+i])/i
                ind :=indref+i
        line.new(x1=bar_index[indref],y1=f[indref],x2=bar_index[ind],y2=f[ind],color=#FF5733 )


tunnel(-1,close[0],6)
```

the line is relative to the last 6 points of the f function

But my problem is the fact that it repeat the process for all the point and not only for the first one as I should expect, so how should I do to success?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It's not really clear. Could you please edit your question to provide some more information? Preferably with your entire script. And if you can, also a screenshot on which you draw the expected outcome. This way, the community can better assist you.

Comment: i did it, is it good? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for updating your question. It's more clear now.
Is this what you're looking for?

```
//@version=4
study("Mon Script",overlay=true)

var lookBack = input(defval = 6, title = "LookBack bars", type = input.integer)

// Define lines
var hiLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0, color=color.yellow)
var loLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0, color=color.yellow)

hiBarOffset = 0 - highestbars(high, lookBack) // high can be omitted, because it's default. Returned values are negative, so flip sign.
loBarOffset = 0 - lowestbars(low, lookBack)   // low can be omitted, because it's default. Returned values are negative, so flip sign.

if barstate.islast
    // Redraw high line
    line.set_xy1(hiLine, bar_index[hiBarOffset], high[hiBarOffset])
    line.set_xy2(hiLine, bar_index, high)

    // Redraw low line
    line.set_xy1(loLine, bar_index[loBarOffset], low[loBarOffset])
    line.set_xy2(loLine, bar_index, low)
```

Comment: there is your result : https://www.tradingview.com/x/OoZeNBZd/ i'm not sure, in fact there is only one line and that's good, but i'm not sure about a random line

Comment: That's because you only look 6 days back, and today is the lowest low of those 6 days, so it's plotting a line onto itself on that last bar (which can't be seen of course). This is the [CAC40 with 20 day lookback](https://www.tradingview.com/x/40dabMbS/). Zoomed in image [here](https://www.tradingview.com/x/ykLApZ63/)

Comment: there is a misunderstanding I want to surround the graphic with lines like a gift wrap (I've submitted other images)

Comment: my first code is the good one but he repeat the process for each point as if each point is the last one (so there is many line)